# How to create formula in Mac?

Tags: support, mathjax

First,I want to say I study F&Q carefully,and...maybe because I am stupid.I just want to say I still can't get it how to create nice and beautiful math formula.

This is how I do it

For example,I want to create a formula $\int_{}^{}{\tan ^{}\theta d\theta }$
First,open Mac Grapher,then I will create $\int_{}^{}{\tan ^{}\theta d\theta }$ in Grapher,then chose "Copy LaTex Expression",and paste it here.Add $ $.

Is this right?Is there another way?
Sorry for asking such a stupid question.

Answer (score 3):

Just learn basic $\LaTeX$, in one of a million ways, and write it directly. I should also add that exporting $\LaTeX$ formulas usually gives a very bad and inefficient formula, which may cause the belief that the syntax is hard and complicated.

It's not. It's not *very* easy, but it's not too hard to use directly.

**Some resources:**

1. [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).
2. [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).
3. [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).
4. Open any $\LaTeX$-heavy answer, click "edit" and see what sort of code is used to produce the different parts.

Comment: @robjohn: Yes, I realized that I could add some links and whatnot.

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again until people stop recommending clicking the edit button just to see the TeX source: Just right-click on the math and choose Show Math As > TeX Commands.

Comment: @Rahul: When the result is *not* a new window, I'll start recommending it.

Comment: @RahulNarain: new users may not know what is $\LaTeX$ and what is markup. Looking at the raw source is sometimes easier, and shows what is in `$...$` and what is in `$$...$$`. I think both (MathJax contextual menu and edit box) are useful.

Comment: @robjohn, Asaf: Fair enough. I'll stop saying it.